# Unreadable font on Gmail since recent updates in Chromium

Tags: fonts, gmail

Since recent updates in the past two or three days, many of my incoming emails have become unreadable in Gmail.

Specifically:

- This happens only in Chromium (in Gmail). If I open the affected emails in Firefox Gmail, I can read them OK.
- If I change the zoom, whether larger or smaller, I can read the email. But at 100%, I cannot.
- The problem started only a couple of days ago (yesterday, I think).
- Not all emails have this problem. I don't know what separates those that do from those that don't.
- The emails render perfectly on both Windows 7 (Chrome) and Lubuntu 14.04 (Chromium).

See the screen-shots:

**100%** (parts of letters, and entire letters, are missing):

[image: Zoom 100%]

**90%** (readable, though not entirely clear):

[image: Zoom 90%]

**110%** (also readable, though not entirely clear):

[image: Zoom 110%]

The letters are crystal clear on both Windows and Lubuntu.

Presumably, it is something to do with the fonts. But I don't know even where to begin fixing this readability problem.

Please help.

- I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, fully updated

Comment: Maybe you should check there: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=367103 i don't believe the issue have been corrected.

Comment: @PierreGirard Thanks, but I don't have that problem. This is quite different anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with Google Chrome and Outlook.com (I know different site & slightly different browser, but the code should help). Adding this code to `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` (it may need to be created) fixed the issue for me:

```
<match target="font" >
    <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
        <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
</match>
```

This isn't original with me, but I cannot remember where I found the answer as it's been awhile (I just copied my file to here). All I remember is that my searches had to do with Calibri. Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'd love to know what it means, but at least I can read my emails again.

Comment: I can't remember exactly why/how, but I believe it turns off MS's proprietary attempt at an anti-aliasing guide, allowing Linux to do it freely and correctly. (It's embedded into the fonts themselves to aid MS's anti-aliasing engine, but naturally interferes with Linux. This code tells Linux to ignore MS.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I had noticed that the emails were from MS Outlook. Presumably, then, it interferes not only with Linux but also with other operating systems such as Unix (Mac OS).